# How to use semantic-release to publish an Angular library in a Bitbucket repository?

Tags: angular, bitbucket, release, angular-library, semantic-release

I'm working on an Angular Library and I'm trying to make the process of releasing as much automatic as I can. I've been researching different tools and I've seen several that are very helpful:

- [Commitizen](https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli) for commit message format
- [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) to enforce commit format using git hooks
- [Semantic release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) to automatically publish and release new versions and generate a changelog

The point is that it seems that these tools are very well configured to work in environments with GitHub and NPM, but my environment works with Bitbucket and doesn't use NPM to host the library.

So I have several questions:

As you know when you create an Angular library, it is created within a workspace under the "projects" directory. so let's say I have the following structure:

[image]

This code is in one repository, so if I want to publish my library so it can be installed in other applications by using the following in package.json:

```
"my-lib": "git+https://path.to.my.lib.in.bitbucket.git#v1.0.0"
```

Should I have another Bitbucket repository to publish the content in dist folder once is built? or should I commit and push the dist folder in the current repository? I'm a little lost.

How I should configure semantic-release to affect only to the library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dist folder is generated once you have run ng build and it's updated when you apply any changes on your angular files, So Do you mean that you want to host angular in hosting?  Because you shoudn't commit dist folder to repository

Comment: @KenanaReda How should I publish the library then?

Comment: `ts` files don't work in browser, all ts files will be compiled and converted to `js` files , the same for this lib files